# How to save data to local database in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I know to add data to a SQL Server database but don't know to add data to local database that have `.sdf` extension in Visual Studio 2010, please give me code example to add data to local database through C#.

```
string cb = "Insert into tblFees(Salutation,Name) VALUES (@d1,@d2)";  //id  li

cmd = new SqlCommand(cb);
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", cmbSalutation.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", tbName.Text);                

cmd.ExecuteReader();

MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved", "Patient Details", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ExecuteReader` returns data for your query. You need to use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) instead since you are not return any data, you just insert it.

Use `using` statement to dispose your connection and command automatically by the way.

And do not use `AddWithValue` method. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use [`Add` method overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add.aspx) to specify your parameter type and it's size.

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandText = "Insert into tblFees(Salutation,Name) VALUES (@d1,@d2)";
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@d1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cmbSalutation.Text;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@d2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tbName.Text;

   con.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Soner Gönül Sir, This is just my example,please give me some code example to add data to local database that doesn't require sqlserver to be installed on client mashine, thanks for your replay :)

Comment: @SourceCodes What do you mean by _local database_ exactly? Is it LocalDB? Or this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763.aspx ?

Comment: I am Talking About The Database Showed In Screen Shot.. http://s30.postimg.org/d7kiyr04h/image.png

Comment: @SourceCodes I can't see the image since I'm at work now.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to provide a reference to

```
 System.Data.SqlServerCe (in system.data.sqlserverce.dll)
```

And replace

SqlConnection with SqlCeConnection

SqlCommand with SqlCeCommand

Comment: (-_-) ๏Ќ ɨ ώɨℓℓ ţя¥ ๏ɲ ţhąţ (-_-)